# when to use .bind(this) in knockoutjs prototype

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am learning knockout.js and finding a lot of interesting and useful samples on jsfiddle very. I am looking at some knockout.js samples where it uses object.prototype to add methods to a viewmodel object. In some samples it also defines a method in the viewmodel and use .bind(this) while in other samples it doesn't do this. So I don't understand when you have to use .bind(this) with the methods added using prototype?

For example, [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/csxAL/) adds some methods to the ViewModel object using prototype but it also defines those methods in the viewmodel and then uses .bind(this). I don't understand why it needs to do this as I found [another sample](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/x57Lv/) where it doesn't declare the same method in the viewmodel and uses .bind(this).

```
var ViewModel = function(items) {
    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    this.acceptItem = this.acceptItem.bind(this);
    this.revertItem = this.revertItem.bind(this);
}
ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
    //select an item and make a copy of it for editing
    selectItem: function(item) {
        this.selectedItem(item);
        this.itemForEditing(new Item(ko.toJS(item)));
    },

    acceptItem: function(item) {
        if (item.errors().length == 0) { //Check if ViewModel has any errors
            alert('Thank you.');
        var selected = this.selectedItem(),
            edited = ko.toJS(this.itemForEditing()); //clean copy of edited

        //apply updates from the edited item to the selected item
        selected.name.update.call(selected, edited);

        //clear selected item
        this.selectedItem(null);
        this.itemForEditing(null);
        }

        else {
            alert('Please check your submission.');
            item.errors.showAllMessages();
        }
    },

    //just throw away the edited item and clear the selected observables
    revertItem: function() {
        this.selectedItem(null);
        this.itemForEditing(null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript doesn't really have a concept of methods like other languages do. Consider this object:

```
function Foo() {
    this.foo = 12;
    this.bar = function() {
        console.log('This is', this, 'and this.foo is', this.foo);
    };
}
```

When you create a new instance with `var f = new Foo()`, you can call its `bar` property, which happens to be a function:

```
> var f = new Foo()
> f.bar()
This is { foo: 12, bar: [Function] } and this.foo is 12
```

But `f.bar` isn't *really* a method like for example a Python method, which can be both bound and unbound. JavaScript functions which happen to be properties of objects are always unbound:

```
> var b = f.bar
> b()
This is Window {...} and this.foo is undefined
```

When not called as a property of `f`, `this` becomes the root object. In reality, calling `f.bar()` implicitly sets the `this` object of `f.bar` to `f`, like so:

```
> b.call(f)
This is { foo: 12, bar: [Function] } and this.foo is 12
```

To make `f.bar` more like a bound method, you can bind `f.bar` to a particular `this` by using `.bind`, so the previous example works as you'd expect:

```
> var b = f.bar.bind(f)
> b()
This is { foo: 12, bar: [Function] } and this.foo is 12
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It provides very good explanation of .bind function and when to use etc. However I am still bit confused as to why it was used in one sample and why it was NOT used in another sample as they both were doing same thing i.e. adding functions to objects using prototype and using 'this' to access other members it it. In the sample where it is using '.bind' if I remove it and the function declaration from the viewmodel and do it in a similar way as it is done in another sample then it doesn't work. So there is a reason behind it and I want to know why?